# How to display kernel times and Admin processes in Windows 10 taskmanager?

Tags: windows-10, uac, task-manager, elevation

I noticed that comparing to Windows 7, a lot has changed in taskmanager. There are mainly two features I am currently missing:

1.) show kernel times - was present in Win7, is now missing, why?
2.) show Admin processes, or more precisely: show all processes from all users. Even if I open a cmd.exe as Administrator, and start taskmgr.exe, I still don't get a taskmanager running elevated. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run Taskmgr, go to Performance->CPU, do a right click on a graph and select `Show kernel times`

[image]

this shows the kernel time in the graph.

To see all processes, go to the tab `details`.

[image]